# pymongo : How can I get multiple results from filed in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I would like to get every 'ecg_raw' in 'data' itmes that founded by 'name' with python3 pymongo.

If i know 'name' and 'time_info', How can i get 4 ecg_raw datas which time_info == '2018-09-01 00:00:03'

I want to get every ecg_raw data like [[8,2],[1,10],[9,4],[1,9]]

I tried

```
db.g.find({"data":{"$elemMatch":{"time_info":"2018-09-01 00:00:03"}}},{"name":1,"data":{"$elemMatch":{"time_info":"2018-09-01 00:00:03"}}})
```

but it returns only one value like bottom.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5b90d401219e9c9f72cac8c4'), 'name': 'testDog3', 'data': [{'time_info': '2018-09-01 00:00:03', 'ecg_raw': [8, 2]}]}
```

Please help me.

```
> db.g.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b90d401219e9c9f72cac8c4"),
"name" : "testDog3",
"data" : [
    {
        "time_info" : "2018-09-01 00:00:03",
        "ecg_raw" : [
            8,
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "time_info" : "2018-09-01 00:00:03",
        "ecg_raw" : [
            1,
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "time_info" : "2018-09-01 00:00:03",
        "ecg_raw" : [
            9,
            4
        ]
    },
    {
        "time_info" : "2018-09-01 00:00:03",
        "ecg_raw" : [
            1,
            9
        ]
    },
    {
        "time_info" : "2018-09-01 00:00:04",
        "ecg_raw" : [
            10,
            6
        ]
    },
    {
        "time_info" : "2018-09-01 00:00:04",
        "ecg_raw" : [
            1,
            6
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

aggregate([{$match:{'name':'testDog3'}},{ "$unwind": "$data" },{ "$match": {"data.time_info":"2018-09-01 00:00:03"}}])

Comment: sorry. It returns 
{'result': [], 'ok': 1.0}
 in python after 
db.g.aggregate({"$match":{"data.$.time_info":"2018-09-01 00:00:03"}})

Comment: aggregate([{$match:{'name':'testDog3'}},{ "$unwind": "$data" },{ "$match": {"data.time_info":"2018-09-01 00:00:03"}}])

Comment: Solved it. Thank u very much.